# "Blatantly obvious"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

To me, it seems like the word "blatantly" in front of obvious is redundant, but I know this is commonly used. What type of word is "blatantly" as used in this phrase? It doesn't seem to be an adjective or adverb to me since obvious doesn't seem to be a noun or a verb. I was recently told it was an adverb. Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to find out more about good questions. What does your research show? Beyond what it seems to you?

Comment: Obvious is an adjective, and an adverb can modify an adjective, as in this case.  As for the superfluous redundancy, that just seems to be a tritely overused habit of us Americans in the U.S.

Comment: It's an adverb modifying the adjective "obvious." It serves to intensify the  level or degree of obviousness, in the same way "very" serves to intensify "unique," although strictly speaking, neither blatantly nor very are needed. However, I think blatantly is less incorrect, so to speak, than very, especially before unique.

Comment: What's wrong with being redundant? Most language (over 90% by actual measurement) is redundant. Redundancy is a design feature, not a bug. Redundancy allows listeners to understand what people are saying even when the speakers don't know how to say it well.

Comment: There are some people who have decided that the 'adverb' class is ridiculously disparate and unwieldy. I'd call the modifier of an adjective an adjective modifier.

Comment: "Blatantly" is an adverb that adds meaning to the adjective it modifies, in this case "obvious". "Blatantly" and "obvious" do not have the same meaning in all contexts, so it's not clear to me why the asker or anyone else would call this use redundant.

Comment: Seven hours and no answer? I thought it would have been blatantly obvious.

Comment: @rhetorician  I disagree with you on *blatantly* being less correct than *very*. There are degrees of *obviousness*,  but not of *uniqueness*.

Comment: @RichardKayser: You might want to re-read my comment. I didn't say "blatantly" is less correct; I said "blatantly is less INcorrect than the "very" before unique. Today, however, no one blinks an eye when someone says "very unique," although I must say I cringe a bit inside when I hear it. Don

Comment: @rhetorician You're right. I misread your comment. I agree that "blatantly" is less incorrect than "very". In fact, I don't consider *blatantly to be incorrect at all (there are degrees of "obviousness") , but I consider "very" to be totally incorrect (there are not degrees of "uniqueness"). When you cringe, I cringe. Note that "totally incorrect" has it's own issues. :-)

Answer (score 1):

An adverb can modify an adjective, verb, or another adverb.

The meaning becomes clear when you take the two words and use them in a sentence.

It's *blatantly* *obvious* my dear, that you are smashed. Here, give me that other shoe. Now, let's get you to bed.

In the sentence *obvious*, as a predicate adjective after the linking verb *is* describes *it* [the fact she was intoxicated] as an adjective to mean it was easy for him to see and understand what her condition was. It's modified by the adverb *blatantly* to show "To what extent was she drunk?" "Drunk enough so that she could hardly stand or sit to take off her shoes, much less make it to the bedroom on her own."

Comment: Like your answer but might have interchanged he and she, him and her. :-)